# Building a checkbox filter using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON object from which I'm building checkboxes using `ng-repeat` with `orderBy: 'name'`:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:'name'">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{fruit.name}}" id="{{fruit.name}}">
                {{fruit.name}}
            </label>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to sort my items first by "checked" and then alphabetically.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DqfTw/67/

Comment: "Now i want to show checked lists on top and then by alphabetical." - this is the only useful sentence but you made it so vague. reword it.

Comment: @sza OP wants to sort by `checked` first, then alphabetically (assuming by `value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have an additional column in your data for status with default false(unchecked), or as u needed. then use it for ng-model
your data should be as below.

```
 $scope.fruits =
            [{'name':'apple',status:false},
        {'name':'Mary',status:false},
        {'name':'Mike',status:false},
        {'name':'Adam',status:false},
        {'name':'Julie',status:false}]

    }
```

then your html will be as

```
   <ul>
<li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:['!status','name']">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{fruit.name}}" ng-model="fruit.status" >{{fruit.name|uppercase}}</label></li>
<ul>
```

check the below fiddle link. this works perfect as u needed,
http://jsfiddle.net/DqfTw/90/

@Mickael even the updated one didn't work perfectly,

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a checked attribute on your object and then use this in your orderBy clause :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:['checked', 'name']">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{fruit.name}}" id="{{fruit.name}}" ng-model="fruit.checked">{{fruit.name}}</label>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Your fiddle is up to date.

EDIT : because undefined is not strictly equals to false, you can have bugs in order when you checked and unchecked a checkbox. You can initialize checked attribute of each data or use a custom function for checked attribute (a custom function is better in my opinion).
Here is the code :

HTML :

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:[checkedFunction, 'name']">
             <label><input type="checkbox" name="{{fruit.name}}" id="{{fruit.name}}" ng-model="fruit.checked">{{fruit.name}}</label>
         </li>
     <ul>
</div>
```

Your Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = [
        {'name':'apple'},
        {'name':'Mary'},
        {'name':'Mike'},
        {'name':'Adam'},
        {'name':'Julie'}
    ];

    $scope.checkedFunction = function(fruit) {
        return fruit.checked || false;
    };
}
```

Your fiddle is up to date with the second solution.

Comment: Not sure to understand: you can always use "fruit.checked" in a filter (as I did with "orderBy").

Comment: @RamalingaRaju What do you mean by "use ng model to filter data"?

Comment: i am using these checkboxes as filter for another data with multiple checkbox option

Comment: also i have an issue with the solution you provided,
check all the check boxes  working as needed, now uncheck the check boxes it was sorting in reverse i mean uncheck coming first and checked last.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example to bind data with ng-model of checkboxes in ng-repeat: [tutorial here](http://webtoutsaint.com/multiple_checkboxes)

It is a good example with ng-value-true and ng-value-false :

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits"> 
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.name" ng-true-value="{{fruit.name}}" ng-false-value="{{fruit-name}} - unchecked" ng-change="filterMultipleSystem()"/><br/> 
</div>
```